# get row from AWS dynamoDB table with cognito authentication

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have AWS dynamo DB table where I store information for AWS Cognito users. I created the table to be private so that only the owner of a row in the table can read/write the data (based on cognito authentication). I need to get the data for the user through a lambda function. I created the IAM role for the function in this way:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "dynamodb:Query",
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXX:table/tablename"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

In the lamba function (node.js) I need to get the information stored from the user so I call:

```js
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: 'latest' });

var params = {
    TableName: tablename,
    Key: { 'id': {S: event.queryStringParameters.user_id}
    }
};
ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Success", data);
    }
});
```

I get the error:

```
    Error { AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/lambda_dynamo/getPmtDetails is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource
```

How can I call getItem with the cognito id in order to retrive the row that belong to the user?

Comment: How are you getting event.queryStringParameters.user_id? By which I mean exactly what are you adding to this event when you create it? Have you checked its a valid cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub?

Comment: I use the id from the cognito session. Using JavaScript Amplify library I get it from currentSession() method.

Comment: But how are you getting the id_token? Im trying to establish whether you are taking it from the AWS Token Endpoint correctly. The thing you think is the Cognito sub might not be one.

Comment: The id I'm using is something like: us-east-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: The Cognito sub doesn't have a region on it. If you look in your database the keys will have the format xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Are you passing in a user_id with format us-east-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx? I can check your approach if you include details of how you are getting that user_id

Comment: yeah I'm using the wrong sub. Tnx for pointing me to it!  For what I read, the lambda function needs to assume the role of the user. Since the lambda function is called from the api gateway after login, do I have the user reference somewhere? how can the lambda function assume the role?